# Moving parallel

Tags: armature, bones

How to make the bones move so that they dont go into the x axis, while I'm moving the foot IK Bone. To explain it better, the picture shows, how I dont want to have it, because the upper bone off the leg as well as the knee are going in unrealistic directions and I want it to be only in one way so I can create a walk animation. Can somebody help me?[image: strange knee direction]

Comment: is it not working with a pole target? also, you need to bend the knee a bit in Edit mode

Comment: no, without a pole target

Comment: So try with a pole target

Comment: It didnt work out unfortunately

Comment: Could you please share your file, at least the armature?

Comment: how to implement a file here in comments?

Comment: oh nvm, I fixed the problem

Comment: If you fixed the problem then please add an answer below so other people can learn from your solution.

Comment: I forgot some things like remove parent from  the Armature of the IK Bone and I forgot to extend the chain lenght, therefore some strange stuff happened from time to time.